# JavaEE Container Managed Transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, jakarta-ee, transactions, javabeans

May i please ask for your help here. My knowledge of how a container managed transaction works under the hood is limited, in fact i have no idea.  I have looked at several other questions that are similar to this one, most of them make reference to Spring, and i'm NOT using spring framework, i couldn't get a solution so i decided to ask.

I am trying to get a simple persistence to work without me explicitly writing the transaction code using `begin()` and `commit()` etc. I am using Hibernate's implementation of JPA, the app server i use is "WildFly version 10.1 Final." My `persistence.xml` looks as follows :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

    <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence
       http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_1_0.xsd"
        version="1.0">

        <persistence-unit name="PostgresUnit" transaction-type="JTA">
            <class>beans.entity.Customer</class>
            <properties>
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="org.postgresql.Driver" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/mydb" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="postgres" />
                <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="password" />
                <property name="hiberate.flushMode" value="FLUSH_AUTO" />
                <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update" />
            </properties>

        </persistence-unit>

    </persistence>
```

I have an Entity bean `Customer` :

```
    @Entity
    @Table ( name = "Customer" )
    public class Customer {

      @Id
      @GeneratedValue ( strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY )
      private int id;

      @Column ( unique = true )
      private long customerNum;// Domain key attribute.

      private String name;

      private String surname;

      private Date dateOfBirth;

      public Customer ( ) {
      }
    //...getters and setters and so on...
    //......

  }
```

I have a session bean `CustomerService` :

```
@Local
public interface CustomerService {
  void addCustomer( final Customer customer );
}

@Stateless
@TransactionManagement ( TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER )
public class CustomerServiceImpl implements CustomerService {

  @Inject
  private CustomerResource customerResource; // Injection point using CDI

  @Override
  public void addCustomer( final Customer customer ) {
    customerResource.addCustomer( customer );
  }
}
```

`CustomerResource` Looks like this :

```
@Local
public interface CustomerResource {
  void addCustomer( Customer customer );
}

@ManagedBean // javax.annotation.ManagedBean...
public class CustomerResourceImpl implements CustomerResource {

  @PersistenceContext ( unitName = "PostgresUnit" )
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  @Override
  @TransactionAttribute ( TransactionAttributeType.REQUIRED )
  public void addCustomer( Customer customer ) {
    entityManager.persist( customer );
    entityManager.flush();
  }
}
```

When i deploy my app, the deployment of my `war` is successful all dependencies are injected, i add a customer via a simple JSP view as i have been doing all along working with `RESOURCE_LOCAL`transaction-type (when everything was working fine) now the code runs but NOTHING HAPPENS. I get no Exception or whatsoever, The Customer is NOT persisted to the customer table. It's like the transaction is not even happening. What am i missing here.